# "auf" and "gehören"

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

I knew the meaning of this sentence that we should place the napkin in our laps, but I want to know why there is *auf* preposition in this sentence. Besides previously, I have checked dictionaries, and I didn’t find any specific preposition for *gehören*.

> Beim Essen gehört die Serviette auf den Schoß und nicht in den Hemdkragen.

Comment: _"I didn’t find any specific preposition"_ There isn't a specific preposition, one can use _gehören_ with _auf,  in, über,  unter, etc._

Comment: "gehören" (in this context) expresses that something ought tp be in a certain position. This position could be described by *any* spatial preposition; and of course, it is also possible to describe a desired status that is not even a spatial relation (Der Hosenstall gehört geschlossen, die Hände gehören gewaschen, ...)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that's helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The English say in the lap, the Germans say on top of the lap. It's as simple as that. Not all prepositions translate 1:1.